# JAXB: multiple tags of the same kind in a specific order

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have a rather unusual XML-format I need to marshall and unmarshall:

```
<a>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
  <d></d>
  <c></c>
  <d></d>
</a>
```

The code that I was expecting to work but didn't is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlType(propOrder={"b", "eList"})
@XmlRootElement(name="a")
public class A {

    @XmlElement(name="b")
    private String b;

    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(name="c", type=String.class),
        @XmlElementRef(name="d", type=String.class)
    })
    @XmlMixed
    private List<String> eList;
}
```

The result is sadly missing the correct order (I need the b,c,d,c,d order):

```
<a>
  <b></b>
  <c></c>
  <c></c>
  <d></d>
  <d></d>
</a>
```

I tried different things like @XmlMixed, sub-objects with @XmlPath but nothing worked for me. Any hints or links? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't mind using a different JAXB provider. So suggestions using MOXY etc are welcome!

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If yes, How have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you below solution

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "a", propOrder = {
    "bs",
    "cs",
    "ds"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "a")
public class A
    implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 1234567890L;
    @XmlElement(name = "b")
    protected List<String> bs;
    @XmlElement(name = "c")
    protected List<String> cs;
    @XmlElement(name = "d")
    protected List<String> ds;

    public List<String> getBS() {
        if (bs == null) {
            bs = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.bs;
    }

    public List<String> getCS() {
        if (cs == null) {
            cs = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.cs;
    }


    public List<String> getDS() {
        if (ds == null) {
            ds = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.ds;
    }

}
```

and you might apply also an xsd validation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="http://yourNamespace" xmlns="http://yourNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

   <xs:element name="a" type="a" />
    <xs:complexType name="a">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element name="d" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```